# Lua network.request to retrieve JSON with square brackets

Tags: json, lua

Hopefully a simple question with Lua. I have a problem accessing JSON data. I write the following:

```
item3 = decoded.items[1].rights
local myText = display.newText(sceneGroup, item3, 150, 80, native.systemFont, 16 )
    myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
```

But error comes up

```
C:\Users\...\data_workingbasics.lua:57: bad argument #2 to 'newText' (string expected, got table)
stack traceback: 
[C]: in function 'newText'
```

I think the problem is JSON data looks like below and I don't know how to fetch this data with square brackets.
Do you know how to write the right path?

```
"rights":["http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/"],
```

By the way, I also tried `item3 = decoded.items[1].rights[0]` but get the following error:

```
C:\Users\...\data_workingbasics.lua:57: bad argument #2 to 'newText' (string expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'newText'
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be `item3 = decoded.items[1].rights["rights"]`. If not, use some old-fashioned debugging and add print statements to display properties of the table. For example:

```
print(#decoded.items[1].rights)
```

Or iterate through the tables keys and values to see its structure:

```
for k, v in pairs(decoded.items[1].rights) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Determine what you are working with.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried the first one and got, "1", and the second one "1 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/". So, I found out `item3 = decoded.items[1].rights[1]` is the correct one. Very strange, because the data don't seem to be an array. But somehow [1] is how I could fetch the data. @anyone any possible explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Sure - common practice in Lua is to use 1-based indexing, not 0 (I missed that in your question when you tried `[0]`). The JSON object is just being decoded into a Lua table starting at index 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! Good to know.